# AngularJS arranging a group of directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I had an ng-repeat with a directive:

```
<div class="container">
  <div ng-repeat="p in people">
    <my-element></my-element>
  </div>
</div>
```

Two questions:

1. How can I pass the model p to the directive?
2. How can I modify all the directives 'myElement'? For example, if they all had an image and I need to set their absolute position using a bin packing algorithm.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything you want in your directive can be passed via `$scope`. You can specify style in the `templateUrl` file or the `template` property:

```
.directive('myThing', function() {
  //
  //<--it's perfectly valid to do any computations and/or setup here-->
  //
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      ngModel: '=', //<--this links ng-model attribute into directive
      myP:'='//<--this links my-p attribute into directive
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, tabsCtrl) {
      tabsCtrl.addPane(scope);
    },
    templateUrl: 'my-thing.html' //<--you could specify style in the template
  };
});
```

So - you could pass `p` as the model or as the `my-p` attribute:

```
<my-element my-p="p"></my-element>
```